# Install webserver without root access

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have a centOS server. I do not have access to the current web server, so I would like to install apache or something, so that I can make changes to the configs. Is there a way to do this in Linux?

Comment: depending on the config change you need to make you might just be able to just make the changes with .htaccess or ask your hosting provider to make them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile the source in your home directory and run it from there.  However, you will be subject to the limits for your user (`ulimit -a`) and will not be able to bind to a port <1024.

Comment: Heh, you beat me by 19 seconds. :)

Comment: The port to use for this is 8080.

Answer (score 4):

You could manually install Apache (or similar) web server into a directory you have right permissions to. However, as you are not a privileged user you would not be able to run it on ports 80/443 (the default for HTTP/HTTPS). Instead you would have to run it on an unprivileged port greater than 1024. A common port for unprivileged web servers is 8080 and 8443 for HTTP and HTTPS respectively.

Taking this route would be difficult, especially if you are an inexperienced Linux user and you would not be able to use the Centos package manager (yum) to install Apache. If it is a publicly accessible web server and you incorrectly install or configure it, at best you will seriously annoy the server administrator, and at worse compromise the server itself.

So in short, yes it can be done, but if you don't know what you are doing (asking the question here is a strong indication you don't) - then don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could probably install it in your ~/ folder, but you won't be able to make it listen on port 80. In order to do that, the process needs to be started by root.

Answer (score 0):

If the system administrator/web master is friendly you can ask them to allow you to include a file in a virtual host config.

E.g. they define a VirtualHost such as:

ServerName www.somedomain.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/a/dir
Include /path/to/your/config

Where the /path/to/your/config is a file that you control and can write to.

The only problem then would be the ability to reload the config when you edit your config file, which might be overcome with either, sudo access for you to run the apache reload and configtest or a periodic apache config reload, e.g. cronjob.

We use this scenario at work for some servers where there is only one client on the host, but we don't want to give them root, because they keep breaking the box (not just the apache install)

As mentioned above you could also try using .htaccess files, which allow some config override, depending on the webserver's config or the install and run on a non privilged port option.
If you go the non priv port option you may be able to use a URL redirect service, such as some DNS hosting services provide to make the non standard port "more transparent" to end users. I.e. they won't need to append the port num to the URL for their first visit to your site.